# Regex to find and replace only first number

Tags: regex, numbers, notepad++, str-replace

I have a text file and I want to replace first number in every line with something else.

Is there any way to exclude other numbers ?

for example:

```
aha 12 as 12 a 3
asdasd kk3l poweqwop 23 sdld 32 kas
```

I want to replace into

```
aha X as 12 a 3
asdasd kkX poweqwop 23 sdld 32 kas
```

Comment: Which language/tool are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find: **`([^\d]+)(\d+)([^\d]+.+\r?\n)`**

Replace with: **`$1X$3`**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`sed -r 's/\d+/X/' file`

Without g at the end of the `s///` command, the replacement is done only once, for the first occurrence.